# rake db:setup db:test:prepare won’t behave as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I have a `script/cibuild` script, which I run on [Semaphore Hosted CI Service](https://semaphoreapp.com/)), that contains…

```
time bundle exec rake db:setup db:test:prepare --trace; echo
```

… to setup the database and check if are there any pending migrations, but for some reason this won’t work not even on my development machine.

Striping down `script/cibuild`’s contents boils down to this:

```
export RAILS_ENV=test
export RACK_ENV=test

# options to rake 'spec' task
export SPEC_OPTS='--color --format documentation --backtrace spec'

echo "Installing dependencies..."
time bundle install --deployment; echo

echo "Setting-up database..."
time bundle exec rake db:setup db:test:prepare --trace; echo

echo "Running tests..."
time bundle exec rake spec --trace; echo
```

Build will eventually fail with the following trace on Semaphore:

```
Running tests...
** Invoke spec (first_time)
** Invoke test:prepare (first_time)
** Invoke db:test:prepare (first_time)
** Invoke db:abort_if_pending_migrations (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:abort_if_pending_migrations
You have 10 pending migrations:
  20130418144736 CreateUsers
  20130424134725 CreateCollections
  20130506124127 AddStaffToUsers
  20130513115848 CreateResourceTypes
  20130513140804 InstallHstore
  20130513141924 CreateResources
  20130513144332 AddCredentialDataToUsers
  20130523155851 RenameSubscriptionDataInResource
  20130531110125 AddProfilePictureToUser
  20130722101545 AddEmailIndexToUser
Run `rake db:migrate` to update your database then try again.
```

Now it seems to me that the problem may not be at `db:setup db:test:prepare` line, but instead when `rake spec` is run. I am not sure.

In any case if I run in my development machine…

```
rake db:drop:all
rake db:setup db:test:prepare
```

… I will end up with an empty test database (“empty” as in no tables, etc.) whereas…

```
rake db:drop:all
rake db:setup
rake db:test:prepare
```

… will create also test database, as expected.

One might think as if I didn’t run `rake db:migrate` at some point (hence 10 pending migrations), but I am pretty confident that this isn’t the case. Although I don’t have a `db/schema.rb` file, rails should apply all the migrations to get to the final database schema just fine.

Any ideas, please? Thank you.

**Update:**

I kind of suspect that the issue might be related to setting `RACK_ENV` and/or `RAILS_ENV` environment variables to `test`. This *seems to* mess things up a bit.

Comment: i guess that the problem is with the rails environment. when this is set in one place, it wont be overwritten in another place. so executing rake tasks in order might just not work because one rake task should work on a different environment.

Comment: Huh? It’s not clear to me what do you mean by that. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: You need to run rake db:migrate, and you should have a schema.rb file. You say rails should apply the migrations - but you're not telling it to.

Comment: `rake db:setup` ought to apply all the migrations one by one from an empty schema in case there’s no `db/schema.rb` or `db/structure.sql` file.